# React (Next.JS) Import Component After Page Loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components

Im using `react-owl-carousel` package but when i refresh page its throwing an error that says "window is not defined" so thats right. Module trying to access window object before page loaded. I tried to use React.lazy but it not worked and my page throwed another error says `reactdomserver does not yet support suspense` (I tried to change next.config.js to use it but still throwing that error.)

Question is i need something like this

```
import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel" //import it just like that right after page loaded (or window object is accesible)
```

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next.js supports ES2020 dynamic import() for JavaScript. With it you
> can import JavaScript modules dynamically and work with them. They
> also work with SSR.

You can import your component `dynamicaly` and disable server side rendering, this way it will have access to `window`

Create your component and use there OwlCarousel

```
import React from 'react';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';

const OwlComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <OwlCarousel />
        </div>
    );
};
```

and now import that component as dynamic one

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
 
const OwnComponentNoServerRendering = dynamic(() =>
import("../components/OwlComponent"), {   ssr: false });
```

It should work as a charm